# JTextField change value automatically while button pressed

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jbutton, jtextfield

I have a jTextField with two JButtons (Up arrow and Down arrow buttons). Clicking the Up arrow button the numeric value in the textfield increases by 1 (++), and clicking the Down arrow button the numeric value in the textfield decreases by 1 (--).

What I want know is how to automatically "scroll/change" the value while the button is pressed?

Thank you

Comment: You mean keep increasing/decreasing the value while the button is pressed ?

Comment: exactly, is this possible to do without using the spinner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSpinner` is the best way to do this.

But if you want a different implementation, I would suggest using a `MouseListener` attached to the `JButton`s. When one of the button is pressed (the `mousePressed` event), a `javax.swing.Timer` is started. Every x milliseconds (depending on how fast you want the number increased/decreased) a check is made to see if the `JButton` is still pressed and if the mouse is still over the `JButton`. If it is, the number is increased/decreased. When the user releases the mouse (the `mouseReleased` event), the `Timer` is stopped/cancelled.

I never did this, so I don't know for sure that it works. But this is the way I would try it.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but theoretically this sounds right. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

What you probably want is a JSpinner. More specifically a SpinnerNumberModel.

Here is a link to a demo
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: Is there another way without using the JSpinner object?

Comment: *"Is there another way without using the.."*  ..component **designed** for this?  Sure, but why would you use it?  What does the use-case require that a `JSpinner` fails to supply?